# Text not wrapping in p tag from Json text file.(Angular Js)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, ajax

I am retrieve data from JSON and also retrieve some text content but text content not support p tag. I will show you screen shot for hints.
[image]

When we retrieved the Text content then it is showing like this(with p tag).
JSON URL:

> http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bTRWzhCvuG?indent=2

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="chooseProductDescription">
      <div ng-repeat="cat in productDescription">
                <div>{{cat.product.fullDescription}} </div>             
       </div>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
.controller('chooseProductDescription', function($scope, $http){
    $http({
        method:'get',
        url:'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bTRWzhCvuG?indent=2',
        header:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
    }).success(function(data,status,headers, config){   
        $scope.productDescription = data;       
    }).error(function(data, status,headers, config){

    })
})
```

When retrieve the content in View page then p tag not support in angular js. What should i do? please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would assume that `cat.product.fullDescription` doesn't output the `fullDescription` data as raw html, but instead treats it as browser output, eg encodes the html.

Comment: try using `$sce` like this in your `success` `$scope.productDescription = $sce.trustAsHtml(data)`

Comment: @Sachin. This is not works. Explain me more?

Comment: Did you try implementing the `ngBindHtml` ? as it is suggested in the answer?

Comment: @Saching. Yes but i did'nt install sanitize. ngBindHtml can work without sanitize?

Answer (score 0):

use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

```
<div ng-controller="chooseProductDescription">
      <div ng-repeat="cat in productDescription">
                <div ng-bind-html="cat.product.fullDescription"></div>             
       </div>
</div>
```